# Why are my predictions bad, if my accuracy in train is roughly 100% (Keras CNN)

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, convolutional-neural-network, vgg16

In my CNN i have to handle 2 classes in a binary system, I have 700 images each class to train, and others to validation. This is my train.py:

```py
#import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Reshape
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, ZeroPadding2D, Dropout
from keras import optimizers
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

TRAIN_DIR = 'train/'
TEST_DIR = 'test/'
v = 'v/'
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_EPOCHS = 5

def crop_img(img, h, w):
    h_margin = (img.shape[0] - h) // 2 if img.shape[0] > h else 0
    w_margin = (img.shape[1] - w) // 2 if img.shape[1] > w else 0

    crop_img = img[h_margin:h + h_margin,w_margin:w + w_margin,:]

    return crop_img

def subtract_gaussian_blur(img):

    return cv2.addWeighted(img, 4, cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0, 0), 5), -4, 128)

def ReadImages(Path):
    LabelList = list()
    ImageCV = list()
    classes = ["nonPdr", "pdr"]

    FolderList = [f for f in os.listdir(Path) if not f.startswith('.')]
    
    for File in FolderList:
        for index, Image in enumerate(os.listdir(os.path.join(Path, File))):
            
            ImageCV.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(Path, File) + os.path.sep + Image), (224,224)))
            
            LabelList.append(classes.index(os.path.splitext(File)[0])) 
            
            img_crop = crop_img(ImageCV[index].copy(), 224, 224)
            
            ImageCV[index] = subtract_gaussian_blur(img_crop.copy())
            
    return ImageCV, LabelList

data, labels = ReadImages(TRAIN_DIR)
valid, vlabels = ReadImages(TEST_DIR)

vgg16_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=True)

base_model = Model(input=vgg16_model.input, 
                   output=vgg16_model.get_layer("block5_pool").output)

base_out = base_model.output
base_out = Reshape((25088,))(base_out)
top_fc1 = Dense(4096, activation="relu")(base_out)
top_fc1 = Dropout(0.5)(base_out)
top_fc1 = Dense(4096, activation="relu")(base_out)
top_fc1 = Dropout(0.5)(base_out)
top_fc1 = Dense(64, activation="relu")(base_out)
top_fc1 = Dropout(0.5)(base_out)

top_preds = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(top_fc1)

for layer in base_model.layers[0:14]:
    layer.trainable = False

model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=top_preds)
    
sgd = SGD(lr=1e-4, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

data = np.asarray(data)
valid = np.asarray(valid)

data = data.astype('float32')
valid = valid.astype('float32')

data /= 255
valid /= 255
labels = np.array(labels)

perm = np.random.permutation(len(data))
data = data[perm]
labels = labels[perm]

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

datagen.fit(data) 
mean = datagen.mean #This result I put manually in predict.py  
std = datagen.std #This result I put manually in predict.py

print(mean, "mean")
print(std, "std")

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', verbose=1)

model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(data, np.array(labels), batch_size=32), 
                    steps_per_epoch=len(data) / 32, epochs=15,
                    validation_data=(valid, np.array(vlabels)),
                    nb_val_samples=72, callbacks=[es])

model.save('model.h5')
```

And after Run this code, it return a strange result of roughly 100% of accuracy after 5 or 6 epochs. So I try to run my predict.py code: (I know that I have to encapsulate some methods, but for now I just copy and paste all from train)

```py
from keras.models import load_model
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

TEST_DIR = 'v/0/'
pdr = 0
nonPdr = 0

model = load_model('model.h5')

def normalize(x, mean, std):
    x[..., 0] -= mean[0]
    x[..., 1] -= mean[1]
    x[..., 2] -= mean[2]
    x[..., 0] /= std[0]
    x[..., 1] /= std[1]
    x[..., 2] /= std[2]
    return x

def crop_img(img, h, w):
    h_margin = (img.shape[0] - h) // 2 if img.shape[0] > h else 0
    w_margin = (img.shape[1] - w) // 2 if img.shape[1] > w else 0

    crop_img = img[h_margin:h + h_margin,w_margin:w + w_margin,:]

    return crop_img

def subtract_gaussian_blur(img):

    return cv2.addWeighted(img, 4, cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0, 0), 5), -4, 128)

for filename in os.listdir(r'v/0/'):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".ppm") or filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
        ImageCV = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(TEST_DIR) + filename), (224,224))

        img_crop = crop_img(ImageCV.copy(), 224, 224)
            
        ImageCV = subtract_gaussian_blur(img_crop.copy())

        ImageCV = np.asarray(ImageCV)
        
        ImageCV = ImageCV.astype('float32')
        
        ImageCV /= 255  
        
        ImageCV = np.expand_dims(ImageCV, axis=0)
        ImageCV = normalize(ImageCV, [0.23883381, 0.23883381, 0.23883381], [0.20992693, 0.25749, 0.26330808]) #Values from train

        prob = model.predict(ImageCV)
        if prob <= 0.75:  #.75 = 80% | .70=79% >>>> .70 = 82% | .75 = 79%
            print("nonPDR >>>", filename)
            nonPdr += 1
        else:
            print("PDR >>>", filename)
            pdr += 1
        print(prob)
print("Number of retinas with PDR: ",pdr)
print("Number of retinas without PDR: ",nonPdr)
```

The problem is: when I try to predict, roughly all of my preds are poor (the prediction are nonPdr, or class 0, to all images). I already tried to cut off the data augmentation to test, and the result doesn't change how I want. I tried too change my model, change the preprocess (this preprocess is the best I can use for this project) and never happens.

How can I deal with this?

### UPDATE

As @serali said, I tried to cut some layers to reduce the overfitting. This is my model now:

```py
vgg16_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=True)
 
    #visualize layers
print("VGG16 model layers")
for i, layer in enumerate(vgg16_model.layers):
    print(i, layer.name, layer.output_shape)

# (2) remove the top layer
base_model = Model(input=vgg16_model.input, 
                   output=vgg16_model.get_layer("block1_pool").output)

# (3) attach a new top layer
base_out = base_model.output
top_fc1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_out)
top_fc2 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(top_fc1)
top_fc3 = Dropout(0.5)(top_fc2)
top_preds = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(top_fc3)

# (5) create new hybrid model
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=top_preds)
```

As you can see, I cut in the first convolutional block, so my model looked like this:

```
0 input_1 (None, 224, 224, 3)
1 block1_conv1 (None, 224, 224, 64)
2 block1_conv2 (None, 224, 224, 64)
3 block1_pool (None, 112, 112, 64)
top_fc1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_out)
top_fc2 = Dense(16, activation='relu')(top_fc1)
top_fc3 = Dropout(0.5)(top_fc2)
top_preds = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(top_fc3)
```

But, when I try to predict the same images I've trained, the prediction is wrong (with foreign images the result is the same). So, how can I improve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This phenomenon is called **overfitting**. In short it means that your CNN has memorized the dataset, achieving $100\%$ training accuracy. This knowledge, however, doesn't generalize well to unseen data.

I'd suggest reading [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/365806/119015) for more details on overfitting and ways to combat it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was facing this issue before, and then I start with vgg16. So, I'm using transfer learning, dropout, early stopping, normalization.... and still doesn't working!

Comment: Maybe you have a small dataset. How many images are you using for training?

Comment: This is definitely overfitting. You are using transfer learning but on top of vgg16, you have 3 more dense layers with 4096,4096 and 64 neurons respectively. Given that you have only 700 samples each - even with the dropout layers -  it is more than enough to memorize the training data. I would get rid of the additional layers to get a better result.

Comment: @Djib2011 I have 1400 images (700 each class)

Comment: @serali I will try to cut out some layers and soon I give feedback

Comment: @Zico that's a fairly small number of images for training an image classifier. It makes it very easy to overfit.

Comment: @serali, please see my update

Comment: @Djib2011 I know, but I'm applying almost all of techniques to deal with overfitting and still doesn't working..

Comment: Overfitting is prone to occur when the number of features far exceeds the number of samples. You could try increasing the number of samples through data augmentation (stretch, flip, crop, or otherwise distort your images to get more examples), or reducing the number of features through feature selection or pixel averaging.

Comment: @Zico: I did not go through every detail of your code so I don't know if there are any errors here and there but as long as your model is concerned, why don't you remove extra layers completely and just change the last layer so that it is a binary classifier? VGG16 is pre-trained with 1000 different classes so you just need to change that part to 2. I would not add anything else on top of that.

Comment: @Zico VGG has a lot of parameters in the FC layers at the end, which have the capacity to overfit. You could try a network with less FC parameters (e.g. a ResNet-50). Also you could employ techniques like early stopping, etc.

Comment: Thank's to all.

Answer (score 1):

When getting something like a 100% after 6 epochs, it's almost certain  (in my experience at least) that something is wrong at an earlier stage than training...
I would start by debugging and verifying that label extraction in ReadImages is working as expected and comparing manually at least some of the predictions.
A less likely possibility is that there might be something wrong with the train/validation sets themselves....You could try checking they have enough variability for example

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already verify the method and the images. But in this code version when I try to predict some images I used to train, It doesn't predicts right